# Sort a three dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Consider this Array

```
var LIST =[];

LIST['C']=[];
LIST['B']=[];

LIST['C']['cc']=[];
LIST['B']['bb']=[];  

LIST['C']['cc'].push('cc0');
LIST['C']['cc'].push('cc1');
LIST['C']['cc'].push('cc2');
LIST['B']['bb'].push('bb0');
LIST['B']['bb'].push('bb1');
LIST['B']['bb'].push('bb2');
```

I can loop through this array like

```
  for(var i in LIST){

      console.log(i)//C,B
      var level1=LIST[i];

      for(var j in level1){
        console.log(j)//cc,bb
        // etc...
      }

   }
```

Fine.. I have few basic questions.

**1.How to sort the array in each level?**

One level can be sort by .sort(fn) method . How can i pass to inner levels?

**2.Why the `indexOf` method does not works to find the elements in first two levels?**

If it's because of the a non string parameter .. how can i search an array items in array if the item is not string?

**3.How `for(var i in LIST)` works ?**
  I just need a basic understanding of indexing and looping through array ..

Thanks ..

Comment: You should be using the object literal `{}` for most of your code. Arrays (`[]`) should have incremental numeric key values.

Comment: @zzzzBov is correct - your objects are Array instances but you're not using them properly.

Comment: To sort an array use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort "MDN Reference") method with callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIST` is **NOT** a three dimensional array in Javascript, it is just an array.

```
//declare an array which names LIST.
var LIST = [];

//set a property named 'C' of the LIST to be an array.
LIST['C']=[];
//set a property named 'B' of the LIST to be an array.
LIST['B']=[];

//set a property named 'cc' of the 'LIST.C'(which is an array object)
LIST['C']['cc']=[];
//set a property named 'bb' of the 'LIST.B'(which is an array object)
LIST['B']['bb']=[];
```

The fact is you only need to let the last level to be an array, see my example code below.

```
function iterateOrderd(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        obj.sort();
        for (var j = 0, l=obj.length; j < l; j++) {
            console.log(obj[j]);
        }
    } else {
        var sortable = [];
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                sortable.push(i);
            }
        }
        sortable.sort();
        for (var j = 0, l=sortable.length; j < l; j++) {
            console.log(sortable[j]);
            iterateOrderd(obj[sortable[j]]);
        }
    }
}


var LIST = {};

LIST['C'] = {};
LIST['B'] = {};

LIST['C']['cc']=[];
LIST['B']['bb']=[];  

LIST['C']['cc'].push('cc0');
LIST['C']['cc'].push('cc1');
LIST['C']['cc'].push('cc2');
LIST['B']['bb'].push('bb0');
LIST['B']['bb'].push('bb1');
LIST['B']['bb'].push('bb2');

iterateOrderd(LIST);
```

Comment: ok.. thanks .. so here im trying to sort the properties in alphabetical order.. or while looping through that i need to get that in alphabetical order.. how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that `Array` inherits from `Object`.

In JavaScript, any `Object` instance is an associative array(!), so acts like an Array in PHP. For example:

```
var o = {}; // or new Object();
o['foo'] = 'bar';
o[0] = 'baz';
for (i in o) { console.log(i, o[i]); }
```

Sorting an `Object` does not make much sense. `indexOf` would kinda work in theory, but is not implemented.

`Arrays` are ordered lists. `Array` instances have `push()`, `length`, `indexOf()`, `sort()` etc., but those only work for numerical indexes. But again, `Array` inherits from `Object`, so any array can also contain non-numerical index entries:

```
var a = []; // or new Array();
a[0] = 'foo'; // a.length is now 1
a.push('baz'); // a[1] === 'baz'
a.qux = 1; // will not affect a.length
a.sort(); // will not affect a.qux
for (i in a) { console.log(i, a[i]); }
```

I recommend playing around with arrays and objects, and you'll soon get the point.

Comment: is it possible to sort it based on non-numerical index entries in alphabetical order..

Answer (score 0):

What is your sorting criteria ? I mean how will you say array `firstArray` comes before `secondArray`? 
regarding the `for (counter in myArray)`, `counter` will take values of an array element in every iteration.

`for (counter in [0,1,5])`, counter will have values 0, 1 and 5 in the 3 iterations.

In your case, `i` will have values `LIST['B']` and `LIST['C']` in the two iterations and `j` will have values `LIST['B']['bb'], LIST['B']['cc'], LIST['C']['bb']` and `LIST['C']['cc']`.

Both `i` and `j` will be arrays.

Comment: my sorting criteria is just based on the alphabetical order, actually the elements will add in random order..while looping through it I will get in the same order..